# React Native pinch-to-zoom

Tags: react-native

Using RN 0.33.0, my app cannot pinch-to-zoom (Android 6 and iOS 9). I can't find anything in the documentation about zooming, except for ScrollView. Do I just need to wrap my entire app in a ScrollView, or is there a configuration in Android Studio / Xcode to enable that?

Comment: What kind of component is that you want to pinch-to-zoom in to? Wrapping your app in a `ScrollView` would only allow you to scroll

Comment: I want to pinch-to-zoom everything -- so text can appear bigger, images can appear bigger, etc. For ScrollView, I was referring to the `maximumZoomScale` property.